# Parse all the xml files in a directory one by one using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I'm parsing XML in python by ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
tree = ET.parse('try.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

I wish to parse all the 'xml' files in a given directory. The user should enter only the directory name and I should be able to loop through all the files in directory and parse them one by one. Can someone tell me the approach. I'm using Linux.

Comment: all your files are present in same folder or they in folders inside of folder?

Comment: you can use `glob` like `glob.glob('*.xml')`, this will return the list of xml files, and parse accordingly

Comment: They are in the same folder

Comment: @Abhishek, if they are in the same folder with your code:                                                              for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    #fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)   # yeah, omit this line
    print(filename)

Answer (score 22):

Just create a loop over `os.listdir()`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

path = '/path/to/directory'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters As I discovered last night if you want 10 times the speed use: `import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET` and don't worry about changing any code.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: better still: use lxml. Faster, and superior feature set.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def parse_xml(xml_path):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    classname = root.find('.//testcase').get('classname')
    time = float(root.get('time'))
    return classname, time

def main():
    data_folder = 'programming/assignment-1/data/'
    xml_files = [f for f in os.listdir(data_folder) if f.endswith('.xml')]
```