# How to include filename variable inside python xml etree for cycle

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I can't get to solve the problem in my python code and i need some hints.

The fact is that if I use the code without for cycle, directly with

```
tree = etree.parse('filename.xml', parser=parser)
```

everything works like it should. When I try to assign to `file` a variable to iterate filename inside directory the code hangs giving me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/eikaf/test.py", line
>   45, in 
>       ragsocemittente = root.find('.//FatturaElettronicaHeader//CedentePrestatore//DatiAnagrafici//Anagrafica//Denominazione')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

```
path = '/home/eikaf/xml'
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for file in filenames:
        #print(file)
        #print(filenames)
        tree = etree.parse(file, parser=parser)
        root = tree.getroot()


        ragsocemittente = root.find('.//FatturaElettronicaHeader//CedentePrestatore//DatiAnagrafici//Anagrafica//Denominazione')

        if ragsocemittente is None:
            ragsocemittente = ''
            ragsocemittentecognome = root.find('.//FatturaElettronicaHeader//CedentePrestatore//DatiAnagrafici//Anagrafica//Cognome')
            ragsocemittentenome = root.find('.//FatturaElettronicaHeader//CedentePrestatore//DatiAnagrafici//Anagrafica//Nome')
            #print("Ragione Sociale Emittente " + ragsocemittentecognome.text + " " + ragsocemittentenome.text)
            ragsocemittentegiust = str(ragsocemittentecognome.text + " " + ragsocemittentenome.text).ljust(32)
        else:
            #print("Ragione Sociale Emittente: " + ragsocemittente.text)
            ragsocemittentegiust = str(ragsocemittente.text).ljust(32)


        print(ragsocemittente.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is at least one file in the directory which is not a valid XML file. Are you able to run the same code (with for cycle) by just keeping the filename.xml in the directory?

Comment: i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679467/parse-all-the-xml-files-in-a-directory-one-by-one-using-elementtree but is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it works. If i replace `file` with `filename.xml` inside `tree = etree.parse(file, parser=parser)` i can get the same result for "n" file existing inside the directory.

Comment: Don't change the code at all. Just keep one file 'filename.xml' in the directory located at: '/home/eikaf/xml', and run the same code.

If the code runs successfully, add few more files and run the same code. If runs successfully replace this set with another set of files and so on. Until you find the problematic set. Then narrow down your hunt in the problematic set.