# Multiple XML files in directory Python

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I am fairly new to Python and this community has been a great help! I am learning a lot. I'm trying to use this existing code to loop through multiple XML files in the same directory. Currently, the code is looking at one specific file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("your_file.xml", "r"), "xml")

d = {}
for tag in soup.RECORDING.find_all(recursive=False):
    d[tag.name] = tag.get_text(strip=True)

df = pd.DataFrame([d])
print(df)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse all the xml files in a directory one by one using ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679467/parse-all-the-xml-files-in-a-directory-one-by-one-using-elementtree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you...

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

files_in_folder = os.listdir(folder_path)

result = list
for file in files_in_folder:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(file, "r"), "xml")
    d = {}
    for tag in soup.RECORDING.find_all(recursive=False):
        d[tag.name] = tag.get_text(strip=True)
        result.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Comment: The above will fail if the current working directory is different from `folder_path`.

Comment: Thank you! I added the folder path but I get this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: sorry, missed to add this:
replace open(file, "r") with open(os.path.join(folder_path, file), "r")

Comment: No problem, thank you. I still get the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' I did not get this error with my original code.

Comment: When i print(soup) it is only showing the first line of the file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> and not the contents so its not finding tag RECORDING

Comment: You might need to check the value of the soup.RECORDING, it's value might be None.
If you want we can have a meeting and let's fix this together

Comment: Thank you. I will troubleshoot some more and reach out if I need help. Thanks again for your help I appreciate your time

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `walk` function of `os` module for this

```
import os

path = 'path/to/directory'
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), "r"), "xml")
```

Comment: You should do `os.path.join(dirpath, filename)`. Try your code as is with files in subfolders.

Comment: Thank you - I also get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: This seems to be due to the content of the XML file itself more than walking the directory to open it.